# Why Rospy does not work ros2 python environment?

Tags: python, opencv, ros2

In the python virtual environment, I can not import rospy. Why? I need it to publish and to subscribe the image_raw.

Comment: You are asking about `rospy` and tagged your question with `ros2`. `rospy` is specifically for `ros1` and with `ros2` you'd have to use `rclpy`. Please clarify whether this concerns `ros1` or `ros2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ros2`, you'd have to use `rclpy` instead of `rospy`.
`rospy` does not exist anymore with `ros2`, so you also cannot import it. `rclpy` is the new client library that builds on top of ros2' `rcl`. See [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Concepts/About-ROS-2-Client-Libraries.html?highlight=rclpy) for further information.

Generally, `ros2` is well documented with many demos and tutorials. See [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html) for a simple subscriber/publisher tutorial.

Here is also a quick example of how to subscribe and publish on an image topic:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
    
class SimplePubSub(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('simple_pub_sub')
        self.publisher = self.create_publisher(Image, '/image_processed', 10)
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            Image, '/image_raw', self.img_callback, 10)

    def img_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info('processing image....')

        # msg = ......

        self.publisher.publish(msg)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    simple_pub_sub = SimplePubSub()
    rclpy.spin(simple_pub_sub)
    simple_pub_sub.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node 
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
import cv2 
    
class SimplePubSub(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('simple_pub_sub')

        topic_name= 'video_frames'

        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(Image, topic_name , 10)
        self.timer = self.create_timer(0.1, self.timer_callback)

        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.br = CvBridge()

        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(Image, topic_name, self.img_callback, 10)
        self.subscription 
        self.br = CvBridge()


    def timer_callback(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()     
        if ret == True:
            self.publisher_.publish(self.br.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame))
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing video frame')


    def img_callback(self, data):
        self.get_logger().info('Receiving video frame')
        current_frame = self.br.imgmsg_to_cv2(data)
        cv2.imshow("camera", current_frame)   
        cv2.waitKey(1)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    simple_pub_sub = SimplePubSub()
    rclpy.spin(simple_pub_sub)
    simple_pub_sub.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```